# Unable to use Gson library in Android project

Tags: android

I'm not sure why this particular lib is giving me trouble when others do not. I did the following to try to narrow things down:

1.) in Eclipse, new Android project
2.) Copied gson-1.7.1.jar to lib/ 
3.) right clicked gson-1.7.1.jar, added to build path
4.) added this to boiler plate main activity: Gson gson;
5.) project throws this exception on runtime:

```
04-14 13:50:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1020): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-14 13:50:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1020): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.Gson
04-14 13:50:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1020):     at com.nerdsoft.client.GsonTestActivity.onCreate(GsonTestActivity.java:17)
04-14 13:50:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1020):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-14 13:50:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1020):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-14 13:50:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1020):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-14 13:50:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1020):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-14 13:50:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1020):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-14 13:50:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1020):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-14 13:50:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1020):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-14 13:50:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1020):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-14 13:50:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1020):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 13:50:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1020):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-14 13:50:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1020):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-14 13:50:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1020):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-14 13:50:23.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1020):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your `lib` folder name to `libs` and re-run it.